# SQL Server Stored Procedure Returning multiple OUT Parameters

Tags: sql-server

I am converting an Oracle Stored Procedure where the Stored Procedure is returning two INPUT parameters at the same time to my application.

Is it possible to return two OUT Parameters with values set in the stored procedure back to the application using SQL Server Stored Procedures.

My SQL SP is working fine, but I have only been able to return one of the two input parameters.

If it is possible can someone post an example?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't RETURN data from a stored procedure.  RETURN is for success or failure codes only, and is basically obsolete.  You assign OUT parameters (as in @Larnu's answer) or send resultsets, using a SELECT (or FETCH) without INTO in the body of the procedure.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) explains it all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server supports multiple `OUTPUT` parameters, just define them as `OUTPUT` in both in the procedure *and* your call to it:

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProc @In int, @Out1 int OUTPUT, @Out2 varchar(10) OUTPUT AS
BEGIN

    SELECT @Out1 = @In + 1,
           @Out2 = CONCAT(@In, 1);
END;
GO

DECLARE @In int = 7;
DECLARE @O1 int, @O2 varchar(10);

EXEC dbo.SomeProc @In, @O1 OUTPUT, @O2 OUTPUT;
SELECT @O1, @O2;
GO
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=64290c71fdc14b4e7d16d08c9989bd05)